# PHP Regex verses Dot Net Regex for date pattern mm/dd/yyyy in a string

Tags: c#, php, regex

I wanted to extract the date pattern "mm/dd/yyyy" from a string, for example, given the string:

"The quick brown fox on 4/26/2018 decided to jump over the moon"

I wanted to extract this date pattern from any string in C#. In starting out I used:

https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1

Using the pcre (PHP) flavor I came up with the following and it seemed to work well for this date format in any sentence:

\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b

However when I put this in my C# code it would not work:

```
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b");
        MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(myTestString);  //get mm/dd/yyyy
        string date = mc[0].Value;
```

mc comes out false? No match?

So I went over to a couple Dot NET Regex test sites and tried
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b    - it fails on those sites also for my test string above.

My question is why does "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b" work on the PHP regex to extract the date of format mm/dd/yyyy from any string but it does not work with C# regex as shown above?

Comment: [Your pattern does not match your input](https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/10). Another point is you used `\b` word boundary and it means there won't be a match before `_` or letter or digit. And besides, there is no need escaping `/` char.

Comment: In addition to what @WiktorStribiżew said, there are various regex dialects, and it's very frequent that there are differences between them.

Comment: I edited my pattern as shown now it does work to match this pattern over at https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1

Comment: @NealDavis `\/([0-9]+)[^\/]*$` is not matching any date strings, it just matches `/`, then captures 1+ digits into Group 1 and then matches any 0+ chars other than `/` up to the end of string.

Comment: But "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b" seems to work fine at https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1 - as long as date format is mm/dd/yyyy which is the only date format I need to worry about? I do need the escape character before /

Comment: *I do need the escape character before `/`* - who forces you to do that? Tell them they are wrong. Rule 0: always test your patterns in the target environment, or at least in regex testers that are compatible with your regex flavor. **See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/SCb7YZ)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - go to https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1 but in a string with the date mm/dd/yyyy and then use "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b" to parse the string. It will work - then try to take out the escape \ in front of the / it will give you an error - are they wrong?

Comment: @NealDavis I went and [**here is the result**](https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/11). **There is no need escaping `/`**. Even in a PCRE regex, though you said you are using it in .NET, where **there is no need - and even sometimes harmful - to escape `/`**. AND: [**your code works**](https://ideone.com/SCb7YZ).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks for your code don't know what I was doing - I thought I tried with out escaping the / - I'll revisit my code thanks for your code and help very much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to clarify that for the date pattern mm/dd/yyyy in a string the regex pattern -

@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b"

does work in both Dot NET C# and at https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1. What I was doing wrong at https://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1/1 was I was not putting the "@" before the regex string this made it so that I had to use the escape char . Thanks to Wiktor Stribizew I was able to go back and revisit this.

In addition in my C# code I had a test string that was bad it was a copy and past string and must have had some weird control characters in it and that was the reason that regex pattern @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b" was not working. I went back to my code and deleted the original test string and retyped it and now @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b" works to extract the date pattern mm/dd/yyyy from any string it is embedded in. Again I have to give credit and thanks to Wiktor Stribizew for his help on solving this issue.

Note: my string was coming from the windows 7 embedded system event log ID 6008 event.message for some reason there is some type of invisible characters / non printable characters in that string ultimately I had to use the following regex on the string to clean it:  cleanString = Regex.Replace(message, @"\p{C}+", string.Empty);